# search if 3 elements appear in same row

Tags: java

I need to search if `ival` contains 3 strings in the SAME  row. The following code do not assign count = 1 even if I have such a row

```
String[][] ival = new String[10][7];      

for (int y = 1; y < ival.length; y++) {     
    for (int z = 1; z < ival[y].length; z++) {  
        XSSFCell cellValue = sheet1.getRow(y+1).getCell(z+3); 
        String str_cellValue = cellValue.getStringCellValue();                  
        ival[y][z] = str_cellValue;
    }
}
```

Now I want to search if 3 particular elements appear in the same row.
There will be only one such row in a array.

```
count = 0;     
int y = 0;     

while (y <= 10) {                   
    for (int z = 0; z < = 7; z++) {
     Set set1 = new HashSet();
     set1.add(ival[y][z]);

        if (set1.contains("one") && set1.contains("two") && set1.contains(("three"))) {                    
            count = count +1; 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: How on Earth can `ival[y][z]` be equal to three different strings **at the same time**?

Comment: I think you wanted `||` and then after the loop if `count` is equal to three then that is the row

Comment: Please format your code properly. Currently your brackets do not even add up.

Comment: Thank you for the comments ..i have taken the elements to a Set. Can you please check now?

Comment: Move your `if` out of `for`. You start checking before your set is fully populated.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to have no sense - for example:

```
XSSFCell cellValue = sheet1.getRow(y+1).getCell(z+3);
```

What do you mean by `+1` or `+3` modifitators? Are they meaningless or required?

---

Anyway, to answer your question - to check whether there are three same items in the row you can simply do

```
// In your case you could call this with parameters (sheet1, 3)
public boolean testOccurences(Sheet sheet, int occurences) {
    Map<Object, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(Row row : sheet) {
        map.clear();
        for(Cell cell : row) {
            String stringValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
            if(!map.containsKey(stringValue) {
                map.put(stringValue, 0);
            }
            map.put(stringValue, map.get(stringValue) + 1);
            // Check whether the item is n-th occurence
            if(map.get(stringValue).equals(occurences)) {
                return true;
            }
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am reading the values from excel. It is some particular fields

Comment: @SmanaP still do not understand what those offsets are for :) however if you need them you can still follow my approach but add sth like `if(row.getRowNum() < 1) continue;1 etc